# How to avoid "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on ngModelChange in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dropdown, multi-select

I have implemented (ngModelChange) in my ng-multiselect-dropdown module so that on any selection or deselection of any value, accordingly I push it in an array. But as soon as I load the application, the onChange() function that incorporates ngModelChange loads everytime and it gives error -

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

My code is -

**app.component.ts**

```
onChange(item: any) {
    this.selectedItems=[];
    console.log("inside onChange ,item = ", item)

    console.log("inside onChange, selectedItemsSelected =", this.selectedItemsSelected);

    console.log("inside onChange, this.selectedItems = ", this.selectedItems)
    if (this.selectedItemsSelected.length > 0) {

      for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedItemsSelected.length; i++) {
        this.selectedItems.push(this.selectedItemsSelected[i].item_text);
        console.log("inside onChange, this.selectedItems = ", this.selectedItems)
      }

      console.log("End of onChange, this.selectedItems = ", this.selectedItems)
    }
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <p style="width:50%">
            <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select  API Object'" [data]="dropdownListSelected" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemsSelected"
                [settings]="dropdownSettingsSelected" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" (onSelect)="onItemSelectSelected($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllSelected($event)">
            </ng-multiselect-dropdown>

        </p>
```

**output -on compiling**

```
inside onChange ,item =  undefined
 undefined
inside onChange, selectedItemsSelected = undefined
inside onChange, this.selectedItems =  Array(0)

 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at NodeVennComponent.push../src/app/api-mining/api-venn/node-venn/node-venn.component.ts.NodeVennComponent.onChange (node-venn.component.ts:409)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] 
    at handleEvent (core.js:10251)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11344)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11047)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7710)
    at core.js:9190
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3563)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
```

Comment: Have you declared & initialized `selectedItemsSelected` in component . Somthing like `selectedItemsSelected: any[] = []`

Comment: You should declare selectedItemsSelected as empty array if you want to check its length. Length property is only part of arrays. Upper comment show you to how to declare it.

Comment: Please confirm that `selectedItemsSelected` always has to exist on the object. If it does not always have to be an array, you have to check for it. If it always is an array, you have to make sure it's always initialized. I'll let the others provide you the code then.

Comment: just add one more condition in your if condition like this.

`if (this.selectedItemsSelected && this.selectedItemsSelected.length > 0) {`

Comment: Thank you . I had not initialized the array. Thanks all